# $a|p+1$ if and only if $\frac{a}{p} = \frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

Let $p$ prime be a number and let $a$ be a natural number so that $a<p$.
prove that $a|p+1$ if and only if there are $M,N$ that are naturals so that $a/p = 1/N + 1/M$.
I have tried a lot of algebraic games to get to something like $p+1 = a\pmod{\text{something}}$ to show that $a|p+1$ but I had no success. I really don't know where to begin.

Comment: Is it $M=m$ and $N=n$?

Comment: yes, sorry for the mistake I have edited it.

Comment: Then, first try $p+1=a\cdot s$ and divide by $ps$.

Comment: thank you i will try that! I'll come back if I couldn't get it. but will it help for both sides of the statement?

Comment: That helps with the easy direction.

Comment: and the other direction? do you have any clue?

Comment: You will need that $p$ is a prime.

Comment: The gives you one direction. For the other, do something similar. Show that at least one of n, m is a multiple of $p$, then show that $n = pm$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(For the harder direction.)

**Hint:** Show that $ \frac{a}{p} = \frac{ n+m}{nm} $ implies that $p \mid nm$.

WLOG, let $ m = pk$.

**Hint:** Show that $a = \frac{ n + pk}{nk} $ implies that $ k \mid n$ and $ n \mid pk$.

Conclude that $ n =k $ or $ n = pk$.

Hence, either $ \frac{a}{p} = \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{pk} = \frac{ p+1}{pk}$ or $ \frac{a}{p} = \frac{1}{pk} + \frac{1}{pk} = \frac{2}{pk}$.

So either $ ak = p+1$ or $ a = 1, 2$, and we are done.